# ANTLR4's TreeViewer is not working/showing when running JUnit test cases

Tags: junit, antlr, junit4, antlr4

When calling a method that invokes the ANTLR4's TreeViewer class while running a JUnit test case, the dialog box with the tree doesn't show up.

When calling the same method, with the same arguments normally, the dialog box with the tree shows perfectly.

What am I missing?  Is that something that JUnit disables by default that needs to be enabled to let the dialog box pop up?

Please advise. Thanks!

PS: this is the code I use to display the tree:

```
if (displayTree) {
   System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
   TreeViewer viewer = new TreeViewer(Arrays.asList(parser.getRuleNames()), tree);
   viewer.open();
    Trees.inspect(tree, parser);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code so that others can reproduce it easily?

Comment: Aren't unit tests supposed to run headless? If human interaction becomes necessary then they aren't really unit tests anymore.

Comment: JUnit might set `java.awt.headless` to `true`. If you invert that, maybe the tree viewer will be visisble. Also have a look at http://leshazlewood.com/2009/08/26/linux-javaawtheadless-and-the-display-environment-variable/

Comment: Thanks, guys! I want to be able to display the parse tree for the sake of troubleshooting my unit test. I have a flag in the unit test that can be set to on/off so that the code I added in the PS above is run.

Comment: BTW, setting the headless property to true, prevents the display in the normal (typically non-problematic) mode. So @BartKiers, you are onto something. However, setting to false makes the normal mode work again but the JUnit mode is still broken :-(